How to create a token which is named after another token
I am currently writing an environment where I write questions in. Currently what my goal is to use the points command to write the sub questions points and save the sum of these points per the questions environment into an auxiliary file using \storecounteratend
command from \usepackage{zref}
For example
Question 1 ---
a.   (10)
b.   (20)
Question 2 ---
a.   (30)
b.   (40)
This in second run would (ideally) turn..
Question 1 --- (30)
a.   (10)
b.   (20)
Question 2 --- (70)
a.   (30)
b.   (40)
I tried to define new counters using setcounter{Q\thequestionCount} but it seems I can only get the final value of the counter saved to the .aux file.
I count the environments using the questionCount counter so if there are 3 questions envrionments the setcounter{Q\thequestionCount} would only save Q3 3 times over instead of saving Q1, Q2 and Q3.
I am sure it is an expansion problem but I can't seem to find the proper way to do it.
\newcommand\Question[2]{
  \addtocounter{questionCount}{1}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=!,labelindent=-27pt, itemsep=3pt, topsep=6pt]
  \item[\textcolor{red}{\textbf{[Q\thequestionCount}]}] \textbf{#1}\hspace{1ex}\textcolor{gray!50}{\hrulefill} \hspace{1ex} \label{exam:#2}\addtocounter{examPoints}{#2}#2
  \end{itemize}
}

\newcommand\points[1]{
  \marginpar{(#1)}\addtocounter{Q\thequestionCount}{#1}}

\newenvironment{question}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\the\csname c@questionCount\endcsname}
  \newcounter{Q\thequestionCount}
  \setcounter{Q\thequestionCount}{0}
  \def\ExTitle{#1} %
  \Question{\ExTitle}{\storedcounter{Q\thequestionCount}} 
}{\storecounteratend{Q\thequestionCount}
\endcollect}%}
\END} ```


Can you please add a typical call? Code snippets cannot be used for experimenting.

please provide a complete example which reproduces the output you want to change. I'd use the kernel's properties thing for this and just write the value of a single counter to the aux at each point. then you can pull them back using labels on the next run.
